# Differences between Exchange 2003 Web Services and Exchange 2007 web services

Tags: exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2003

We have Exchange integration into our CRM (diaries and email); we have done this through CRL functions in our SQL 2008 server which handle all the authentication and communication with Exchange 2007 web services. The CLR then presents the functions to developers in SQL Server as regular functions and stored procedures which makes coding wit them simple. We are handling our synching through SSIS to sync the data up.

Unfortunately i cant just install exchange 2003 onto our network Our sales team are in the middle of negotiating a sale that will require me to back migrate the code to work on Exchange 2003. When i am looking to back-port the interface what are the main functional differences between the exchange 2003 and exchange 2007 web services?

What are any potential pitfalls i might face ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no EWS for Exchange 2003.

EWS were introduced in Exchange 2007.

[Exchange Web Services - What You Didn't Know – Exchange Team Blog …](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/03/24/3407117.aspx) (2009-03-25)

Comment: From http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/03/24/450892.aspx, "In Exchange 2007 we introduced Exchange Web Services (EWS)"